# Codeigniter OpenID Authentication

Tags: php, codeigniter, openid, attribute-exchange

I'm new to the OpenID concept and recently tried implementing an [OpenID Library](http://www.codeigniter.com/wiki/OpenID) for CodeIgniter using the [JanRain](http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled) PHP 5 system. However ran into some issues while retrieving simple data from sites like Google and Yahoo...

My config file for the OpenID Library looks like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    $config['openid_storepath'] = 'tmp';
    $config['openid_policy'] = 'test/policy';
    $config['openid_required'] = array('email');
    $config['openid_optional'] = array('fullname');
    $config['openid_request_to'] = 'test/check';
?>
```

Yet, I'm unable to obtain either the 'email' or 'fullname' value.  I've tried filling in other fields (like 'nickname'), but that didn't yield results either. In addition, many other options specified in [JanRain docs](http://documentation.janrain.com/profiledata) (such as 'verifiedEmail' and 'preferredUsername') merely caused an SREG error.

The authentications are successful, as they return a success message, but how can I access the information I've requested?

Edit: Here is the return URL:

```
http://www.{Site}.net/v2/test/check?janrain_nonce=2011-12-10T05:53:01ZFXVT02&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.{Site}.net%2Fv2%2Ftest%2Fcheck%3Fjanrain_nonce%3D2011-12-10T05%3A53%3A01ZFXVT02&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fme.yahoo.com%2Fa%2F{Token}%23df6f7&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fme.yahoo.com%2Fa%2F{Token}&openid.assoc_handle={Handle}&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.{Site}.net%2Fv2%2F&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.response_nonce=2011-12-10T05%3A53%3{Nonce Token}&openid.signed=assoc_handle%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Cmode%2Cns%2Cop_endpoint%2Cresponse_nonce%2Creturn_to%2Csigned%2Cpape.auth_level.nist&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.login.yahooapis.com%2Fopenid%2Fop%2Fauth&openid.pape.auth_level.nist=0&openid.sig=CUa39ZjhGE8nWc7TMvbS8UFlwjQ%3D
```

Thanks!

Comment: Refer this. http://thinkmoult.com/2009/02/22/use-codeigniter-openid-library-to-integrate-openid/

Comment: @RohanPatil I have been following that guide and reading some of the comments, but have yet to find a solution...

Comment: @DFranks i assume that you have redirected user to yahoo/google and they have logged in and are being redirected back to your application.if this is the case can you show the URL and its parameters?

Comment: @umeshawasthi I've edited in the return url above.

Comment: @DFranks why don't you are using attribute exchange in Yahoo it supports this thing and it will give you back what you are expecting from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you in PHP but can show you code i have developed in java which work for yahoo

while i am creating `AuthenticationUrl()` for yahoo this is what i am doing

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
        sb.append(endpoint.getUrl())
          .append(endpoint.getUrl().contains("?") ? '&' : '?')
          .append(getAuthQuery(endpoint.getAlias()))
          .append("&openid.return_to=")
          .append(returnToUrlEncode)
          .append("&openid.assoc_handle=")
```

here is my `getAuthQuery` function

```
 String getAuthQuery(String axa) {
        if (authQuery!=null)
            return authQuery;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0");
        list.add("openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select");
        list.add("openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select");
        list.add("openid.mode=checkid_setup");
        list.add("openid.ns." + axa + "=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0");
        list.add("openid." + axa + ".mode=fetch_request");
        list.add("openid." + axa + ".type.email=http://axschema.org/contact/email");
        list.add("openid." + axa + ".type.fullname=http://axschema.org/namePerson");
        list.add("openid." + axa + ".type.language=http://axschema.org/pref/language");
        list.add("openid." + axa + ".type.firstname=http://axschema.org/namePerson/first");
        list.add("openid." + axa + ".type.lastname=http://axschema.org/namePerson/last");
        list.add("openid." + axa + ".type.gender=http://axschema.org/person/gender");
        list.add("openid." + axa + ".required=email,fullname,language,firstname,lastname,gender");
        String query = Utils.buildQuery(list);
        authQuery = query;
        return query;
    }
```

hope this will give you idea  how to use attribute exchange.

Comment: Thank you very much! In addition to your code, this [replacement](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/A3M_Account_Authentication_and_Authorization) helped solve my problem. :)